# Product attribute information is not saving in the product

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

We use magento 2 and i recently updated the product attributes for the products. Now the new product attributes I created are not saving the content. I have the problem for the attributes price, text, dropdown. The others I didn´t check. I also only have the problem with product attributes I created one week ago. All attributes I created before are working.

Can anybody help?

Comment: did you tried moving the custom attribute values to the "General" Group this sounds silly but it might be the solution in some cases

Comment: how can I do so? I read it before, but I don´t know how to move the custom attributes and where is ´general´? 
I already put them in the ´attribute set´ from the right hand side ´unassigned attributes´ to the ´groups´ @Chikku

Is there a maximum of attributes a product can have?

Comment: check i have posted ans this will clear your doubt regarding the general

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all your help and advice. I contacted our web developers and we have the reason and solution.

There was a problem with the Flat Tables and indexing of it. From a certain amount on, they stopped indexing. But from Magento 2.3x on it, they are optional so we switched them off and on, and after a reindex, it worked.